# Find Files With Similar Name to Folder

Tags: macos, command-line, unix, sed

I'm on OS X, and I have a folder that contains a number of subfolders. There are two things I want to do. The first is to ensure that each subfolder has a file in it of the form [subfolder-name].grade.xml, then I need to search and replace within the appropriate file to make a couple of changes.

For the second part, I know how to use sed on an individual file to do what I need to, but I'm having the problem of verifying that the file is there, and then running the command on it. Any tips on doing this would be appreciated.

**Note: I don't necessarily need a full answer, especially since I'm trying to learn here. A pointer in the right direction would be nice though.**

(I realize that there may be better ways than the command line to accomplish this, but I've needed and will in the future need to do similar things on other Unix-based systems, so I'd rather know :)

Comment: I might be able to give you a better answer if you make your question clearer :-)

Comment: Realized that I had formatted the name of the xml file in a way that made half of it not show up. Sorry about that! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

# Get directory name from argument, default is . 
DIR=${1:-.}

# For each subfolder in DIR (maxdepth limits to one level in depth)
find "${DIR}" -maxdepth 1 -type d | while read dir; do
    # Check that there is a file called $dir.grade.xml in this dir
    dirname=$(basename "${dir}")
    gradefile="${dirname}"/"${dirname}".grade.xml
    if [ -e "${gradefile}" ]; then
          sed -i .bak "s/foo/bar/g" "${gradefile}"
    else
       echo "Warning: ${dir} does not contain ${gradefile}"
    fi done
```

Minor tweaks around Raphink's framework.

Key points:

- check directly for file existence with `[ -e filename ]` rather than running ls
- put all variables in `${variablename}`; often not strictly neccessary, but avoids ambiguity (`${variablename}` and `${variable}name` are clearly distinct, `$variablename` could mean either)
- pass an extension to sed to make backup files. This is both good practice (in case your munging goes wrong), and, on OSX, mandatory (raphink's version interprets `s/foo/bar/g` as being the extension you want on the backup files, then tries to parse the filename as a command.
- Okay, I lied, it's not *actually* mandatory - you could use `sed -i "" "s/foo/bar/g" ${gradefile}` to pass an empty extension, which would cause sed not make a backup.

Comment: It's always a good idea to quote variables that contain filenames. It's better to avoid backticks and use `$()` instead.

Comment: Edited to use $() instead of ``, and to quote variable that contain filenames, because Dennis is correct.

Answer (score 0):

OK, you need to make a script for that. I'll pick bash for it.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Get directory name from argument, default is .
DIR=${1:-.}

# For each subfolder in DIR (maxdepth limits to one level in depth)
find $DIR -maxdepth 1 -type d | while read dir; do
    # Check that there is a file called *.xml in this dir
    if ls $dir/*.xml &>/dev/null; then
       # Loop through xml files found in $dir
       #   or do you actually need to check that there is only ONE file?
       for xmlfile in $dir/*xml; do
          # Do whatever treatment with sed you wish to do
          sed -i 's/foo/bar/g' $xmlfile
       done
    else
       echo "Warning: $dir does not have a *xml file in it"
    fi
done
```

Save that file as a .sh script, then run

```
$ chown +x yourscript.sh
$ ./yourscript.sh /path/to/dir # Path is optional, defaults to .
```